# localStorage clears screen

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm testing out localStorage to see if it can be used in my app, but when I try to store data from a text input box to it, the screen goes blank. How can I fix this? Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function write() {
localStorage.setItem('item',  document.getElementById('input').value);
}

function read() {
var data = localStorage.getItem('item');
document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = data;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="input" type="text" />
<button type="button" onclick="write()">
Write
</button>
<p id="display">
Display
</p>
<button type="button" onclick="read()">
Read
</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what browser (including version) are you testing this in?

Comment: I tested it in an up to date version of Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a function called `write` on the global (`document`) namespace ... call it something else and it works fine

```
<input id="input" type="text" />
<button type="button" onclick="somethingelse();">
Write
</button>
<p id="display1">
Display
</p>
<button type="button" onclick="read()">
Read
</button>​

function somethingelse() {
    localStorage.setItem('item', document.getElementById('input').value);
}

function read() {
    var data = localStorage.getItem('item');
    document.getElementById('display1').innerHTML = data;
}​
```

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/jT58p/)

Comment: @jbabey :-) if you sort by *oldest* i got there first (just) :-)

Answer (score 3):

change your function name from `write` to something else. it sounds like you are accidentally invoking `document.write`, which would blank out your entire page.

Answer (score 1):

The code inside html event handlers is ran effectively like:

```
with(document) {
    with(this) {
        write();
    }
}
```

so your `write` is shadowed (it calls `document.write`). You can simply refer to the correct write with `window.write()`:

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.write()">
```

Ultimately it's better not to use inline html events at all. A simple `button.onclick = write` would have worked, where `button` is reference to the element.

Comment: @ManseUK actually I meant html event handlers, like `onclick="blaa;"`, not real event handlers of course. I forgot to specify that

Comment: I never use the HTML event handlers - either attach using `attachEvent` / `addEventListener` or using a framework - so its nice to understand more about them !